# awk exclude entries that do not satisfy multiple conditions but satisfy others

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, awk, conditional-statements

I am trying to **include** values in my data that have:

1. the second column smaller than 1;

and **exclude** the entries with:

1. the first column equal to 3 and
2. the fourth column larger than 25
3. the fourth column smaller than 35

Basically, excluding the entries that fall between the range of 25 and 35 for column 4 and $1==3. Is there a simple way of doing this without getting too complicated?

Something like:

```
awk '{OFS="\t"} {if (($2 < 1) & !($1==3 && $4>25 && $4<35)) print $0}' file.txt
```

Comment: `awk '$2<1 && $1!=3 && $4<=25 && $5>=35{$1=$1;print}' OFS="\t" file.txt`

Comment: On the whole, it's best to post what will run — I've fixed the missing parentheses for you (two `(` and one `)` were needed).  The single `&` is not a good idea; it should be `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superficially, this should do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {if (($2 < 1) && !($1==3 && $4>25 && $4<35)) print $0}' file.txt
```

as would:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} (($2 < 1) && !($1==3 && $4>25 && $4<35)) { print $0 }' file.txt
```

which could be further reduced to:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} (($2 < 1) && !($1==3 && $4>25 && $4<35)) { print }' file.txt
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} (($2 < 1) && !($1==3 && $4>25 && $4<35))' file.txt
```

The primary changes are to use a BEGIN block to set `OFS` once, and to use `&&` to combine the `($1 < 1)` condition with the exclusion condition.  The single `&` is a bitwise operation, and while the values of the two terms should be 0 or 1 and the bitwise logic should work, it certainly isn't the normal way to deal with it.

Actually, since you're simply printing the input record unchanged, you could even lose the `BEGIN` block and use:

```
awk '(($2 < 1) && !($1==3 && $4>25 && $4<35))' file.txt
```

If the input has tabs separating the fields, those will be present in the output.

These scripts all take exactly what you said in the bullet list, but your text says *'excluding the entries that fall between the range of 25 and 35 for column 4'* and that would often be interpreted as rejecting the values 25 and 35 (as well as 26..34), but it isn't what the bullet list says or the code implements.  The fix is, of course, trivial (`>=` and `<=` in place of `>` and `<`).

You didn't provide any test data and expected output — please aim to do that.  Here's a simple test code data generator (giving 54 lines of output):

```
for h in 2 3 4
do
    for i in -1 0 1
    do
        for j in 24 25 26 34 35 36
        do
            printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" $h $i blather $j
        done
    done
done
```

When run and the output passed to the script shown, the output is:

```
2       -1      blather 24
2       -1      blather 25
2       -1      blather 26
2       -1      blather 34
2       -1      blather 35
2       -1      blather 36
2       0       blather 24
2       0       blather 25
2       0       blather 26
2       0       blather 34
2       0       blather 35
2       0       blather 36
3       -1      blather 24
3       -1      blather 25
3       -1      blather 35
3       -1      blather 36
3       0       blather 24
3       0       blather 25
3       0       blather 35
3       0       blather 36
4       -1      blather 24
4       -1      blather 25
4       -1      blather 26
4       -1      blather 34
4       -1      blather 35
4       -1      blather 36
4       0       blather 24
4       0       blather 25
4       0       blather 26
4       0       blather 34
4       0       blather 35
4       0       blather 36
```

That seems to be correct.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much also for the explanation it is very clear now! THANKS!!!!